FFmpeg RTSP Recording: Video Timestamp Does not Match With Recorded MP4 File Timestamp
I'm currently testing by streaming a 30 fps example flv video using a local Happy-Time RTSP server.
This is the flv file i am streaming with RTSP:

I recorded the video with below ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:6555/test30fps.flv -c copy test30fps.mp4

The resulting video appears visually satisfactory, yet there's a discrepancy between the displayed time on the video and the actual duration of the video file. Although the MP4 file duration is correct (endRecordingTimeMs-startRecordingTimeMs= mp4 file duration), the time displayed within the video does not synchronize precisely with the file's time. Notably, this disparity escalates as the video progresses.
I anticipate the time text overlaid on the video and the file's time to align seamlessly. However, a few seconds of divergence are noticeable, gradually expanding over the video's duration.

Why does this occur and is there any way to fix this?

What is the result of re-muxing without RTSP: ffmpeg -i test30fps.flv -c copy test30fps.mp4? What is the result when just playing test30fps.flv? What is the source of the "time text overlaid on the video"?

Remuxing without RTSP yields the correct video output, with no time disparity. Similarly, when playing the test30fps.flv file, there is no time disparity. However, the issue arises exclusively after RTSP recording.

This is very easy to reproduce and its strange seems like nobody noticed this on internet(?)
